# error on triying executo docker-compose remotely "dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"

Tags: docker-compose

I am triying to publish dockers using docker-compose remotely.

I have created a docker context, then I obtain "failed to open the raw stream connection: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denie" when I make "docker-compose ... up".

```
docker context create remote223 --docker host=ssh://foo@192.168.0.223
docker context use remote223
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
=> foo@192.168.0.223's password:
OK
failed to open the raw stream connection: **dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
```

As context information, when I publish the docker container logger on host with my ssh client I need to do "sudo" to do the docker-compose.

Answer (score 3):

Try checking your permissions for docker.sock

```
$ ls -last /var/run/docker.sock
$ whoami
$ cat /etc/group | grep docker
```

Then you if you don't want to restart docker daemon you can run this:

```
sudo setfacl --modify user:<user name or ID>:rw /var/run/docker.sock

$sudo addgroup --system docker
$sudo adduser $USER docker
$newgrp docker
```

Or if you don't mind restarting use this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
sudo reboot
```